# How to get the GMT value for EDT time zone?

Tags: java, java-7, timezone-offset

it seems that EDT timezone Id is not present in the java.util.Timezone package, if I want to have EDT - (GMT-4:00) and CDT as  timezone, how do I do it. I have posted my code below.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
            String timeZone = "EDT";
            String timeZoneInGMTFormat = "";
            TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
            Date date = new Date();      
            int offset = timezone.getRawOffset();
            timeZoneInGMTFormat = timeZone + " - (GMT"
                    + String.format("%s%02d:%02d", offset >= 0 ? "+" : "", offset / 3600000, (offset 
                    / 60000) % 60) + ")";   
            System.out.print("Time format = " + timeZoneInGMTFormat);
        }
```

Comment: `TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)` probably doesn't return [what you think it does](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/InvalidTimeZoneID). Try printing `timezone`. (And do yourself a favour, come up with less confusable variable names!)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results of one of my tests.

```
Time format = US/Eastern - (GMT-4:00)
Time format = US/Central - (GMT-5:00)
```

I had to use a specific date in the summer to get the daylight-savings offsets.

Here's the code I tested with.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Timezone {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String timeZone = "US/Eastern";
        calculateOffset(timeZone);
        timeZone = "US/Central";
        calculateOffset(timeZone);
    }

    private static void calculateOffset(String timeZone) {
        TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
        
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
        Date date = c1.getTime();
     
        int offset = timezone.getOffset(date.getTime());
        String timeZoneInGMTFormat = timeZone + " - (GMT"
                + String.format("%s%02d:%02d", offset >= 0 ? "+" : "", 
                        offset / 3600000, (offset / 60000) % 60) + ")";   
        System.out.println("Time format = " + timeZoneInGMTFormat);
    }

}
```